# Kids-friendly Windows shell replacement

Tags: windows, software-rec, shell

I'm looking for a Windows shell replacement, which should have the following features:

1. Kids-friendly and kids-proof. Just a list of icons for programs that can be executed, everything else should be hidden or password-protected.
2. Low resource usage. It is going to be used on a computer with 512MB RAM.
3. Windows XP compatible.

I've looked into different Windows shell replacements, like Rainmeter or Emerge Desktop, but they all seem to be overkill and made for a power user. I need something that is very simple and lean, to be used by an 8 year old kid.

Comment: @slhck: Argh! Maybe I can use it as a sort of punishment? No, I cannot be that cruel to my own kids... I think you should delete your comment or someone might take it seriously.

Comment: eww MS bob. Can you customise that in any meaningful way?

Comment: Also, create a user account for the kids. One where they can just click on the icon to login. Make this account very restricted so that they cannot install applications or anything else. Just do what is intended. You can also put an application in the startup menu of they'll be playing just one game. Also, if you're not going to be around when the kids may or maynot need help, I would install Logmein Free on there so you can remote in from work if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like [lightstep](http://litestep.net/) or a [bb varient](http://bb4win.sourceforge.net/) might be a good start. Edit the menu to hide anything you don't need, add a dock of some sort and you're good.

Comment: I've used [Emerge Desktop](http://emergedesktop.org/), which is similar to the above suggestions, with [Toolbox](http://www.cylog.org/utilities/toolbox.jsp) as a launcher (with very big icons in the middle of the screen), and they worked perfectly for a similar purpose (seniors instead of children).

Comment: toolbox looks shiny. I'll need to poke at it at some point

Answer (score 0):

There is also KidsMenu - https://www.glob.com.au/kidsmenu/
It is not maintained anymore. But fits the requirements perfectly.